Express Lucas numbers as a sum of binomial coefficients
So here's the question, prove that $$L_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n}{n-k} \binom{n-k}{k}$$
where $L_n$ is the $n$-th Lucas number.
It really resembles the Fibonacci identity: $$F_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n-k}{k}$$ but the same idea used to prove the bottom one is not feasible on this one.
Any thoughts are appreciated.
Edit 1: Well I just came up with a solution using an alternative definition of Lucas numbers. There is a definition of $L_n$ saying that it counts the number of ways to choose a subset of n points laid on a circle not adjacent to each other. It can be seen from a recurrence. Now I count the same thing directly: Let $L(n, k)$ be the number of ways to pick k points from n points on a circle none of which adjacent to another. I claim $L(n, k) = \frac{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{k}$.
First consider a line of n points and the required points $L'(n, k)$. I either pick the first point or I don't. If I pick the first point there's $L'(n-2, k-1)$, If I don't there's $L'(n-1, k-1)$ so totally there's $L'(n, k) =L'(n-2, k-1)+L'(n-1, k)$. It's easy to see $L'(n, k) = \binom{n-k+1}{k}$. Now if you tie up both ends of the line it becomes a circle, if both ends are picked you get an illegal configuration. Then you need to subtract it: $\binom{n-k+1}{k}-\binom{n-k-1}{k-2} = \frac{n}{n-k} \binom{n-k}{k}$. Sum up k gives the correct result.
But if someone can come up another solution by manipulating binomial coefficients it would be nicer.

Well done to come up with a proof. Instead of editing the quesiton to contain the answer, though, MSE has the option to answer your own question. You should transpose your answer to there, and then accept it

Suppose we seek to evaluate
$$L_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{n}{n-k} {n-k\choose k}.$$
This is
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k} {k\choose n-k}
= [z^n] \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{k} z^k (1+z)^k.$$
Here we may extend to infinity due to the extractor to get
$$n [z^n] \log\frac{1}{1-z(1+z)}.$$
Differentiate to get
$$[z^{n-1}] \frac{1+2z}{1-z(1+z)}.$$
Now according to Wikipedia on Lucas
numbers
the OGF of these is
$$\sum_{n\ge 0} L_n z^n = \frac{2-z}{1-z-z^2}.$$
What we have is
$$[z^n] \frac{z+2z^2}{1-z(1+z)}
= [z^n] \left(-2+2+\frac{z+2z^2}{1-z(1+z)}\right)
\\ = [z^n] \left(-2+\frac{2-z}{1-z(1+z)}\right).$$
This confirms that we have the Lucas number except for the zero index
value which is zero.

Good observation. I wouldn't particularly mind the initial values. Thanks!
